# grep change of line followed by a variable

Tags: grep

I have a file of the following form (with '-' serving as delimiters), and I want to find the appearance of a number only when it follows a delimiter. 
I suppose it's a concatenation of grep '-\n' and $number, but I can't find the way to do it right. thanks..

```
1400
2
132
342
-
76567
1
1234
-
87
2
1400
54
-
```

Comment: By modifying your question like that 3 months later, you're invalidating all the answers you've received. It's also unlikely that people will notice that you've changed the requirements. It would be better to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 5):

#### To find variable before the delimiter:

**Using `awk`:**

```
$ awk '/!!!!!!!!!!!/{print num}{num=$0}' inputFile
342
1234
54
```

**or `gnu-awk`:**

```
$ gawk 'NF && $0=$NF' RS='[!]+'  inputFile
342
1234
54
```

#### To find variable after the delimiter:

**Using `awk`:**

```
$ awk '/!!!!!!!!!!!/{if(getline) print $0}' inputFile
76567
87
```

**or `gnu-awk`:**

```
$ gawk 'NR>1 && $0=$1' RS='[!]+'  inputFile
76567
87
```

Comment: we can shorten your version: `awk '/!!!!!!!!!!!/{if(getline){print}}' file`

Comment: Good that you have provided both the variants; given that the question doesn't make it clear!

Comment: Thanks @devnull. Yea, I was pretty much certain what I had in earlier was what OP wanted until a new answer came in which completely threw my understanding of the question. So went with both! `:)`

Comment: @jaypalsingh The level of _tolerance_ for _not-so-good-quality-posts_ is considerably higher on this site in comparison to SO.  As such, rather vague questions keep getting attracted.

Comment: @jaypalsingh nice!!!!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

The following command

```
grep '!!' -A 1 file|grep -vE '!!|\-\-'
```

will yield

```
76567
87
```

Comment: You read my mind...

Answer (score 1):

grep has a switch `-A` that tells it to print a number of lines after the match. In this case, just use `-A 1` and you'll get ouptut like

```
!!!!!!!!!!!
76567
--
!!!!!!!!!!!
87
--
!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Now just grep out the numbers with `| grep -e '[0-9]'`.

Comment: `grep --no-group-separator -A1 '!' inputFile | grep -v '!'` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

**using AWK**

**To find variable before the delimiter:**

```
awk '{ print $NF }' RS='!!!!!!!!!!!'  infile
```

**Output**

```
342
1234
54
```

**To find variable after the delimiter:**

```
awk 'NR>1{ print $1 }' RS='!!!!!!!!!!!'  infile
```

**Output**

```
76567
87
```

Answer (score 0):

This does a number before a delimiter:

```
sed -n '/[^0-9]/!h;/^-$/{g;/./p}'
```

And this after:

```
sed -n '/^-$/{n;/./!d;/[^0-9]/!p}'
```